# How to use GoogleMap and Autocomplete on same NextJS page?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, next.js, google-maps-api-3

Here is my code:

Page

```
import Map from "@/components/Map";
import { grayMid } from "@/theme/colors";
import { GoogleCoords } from "@/typings";
import { LegacyRef, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Autocomplete from "react-google-autocomplete";

const AddGolfCoursePage = () => {
    const [center, setCenter] = useState<GoogleCoords>({
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
    });
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(2);
    const [listOfCoordinates, setListOfCoordinates] = useState<GoogleCoords[]>(
        []
    );

    const searchRef: LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> = useRef(null);

    const handleClickGolfCourse = (place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult) => {
        const lat: any = place.geometry?.location?.lat();
        const lng: any = place.geometry?.location?.lng();
        setCenter({ lat, lng });
        setZoom(16);
    };

    const handleClearSearchInput = () => {
        if (searchRef.current) {
            searchRef.current.value = "";
        }
    };

    const handleOnRightClick = (e: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => {
        const coords: GoogleCoords = e.latLng?.toJSON() || { lat: 0, lng: 0 };
        setListOfCoordinates((prev) => [...prev, coords]);
    };

    const handleOnDragEndMarker = (
        e: google.maps.MapMouseEvent,
        index: number
    ) => {
        const newCoords: GoogleCoords = e.latLng?.toJSON() || {
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0,
        };
        const coordsCopy = listOfCoordinates.slice(0);
        coordsCopy.splice(index, 1, newCoords);
        setListOfCoordinates(coordsCopy);
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
            {/* Search Input */}
            <Autocomplete
                ref={searchRef}
                apiKey="API_KEY"
                style={{
                    width: "50%",
                    marginBottom: 8,
                    paddingInline: 8,
                    paddingBlock: 4,
                    borderRadius: 8,
                    zIndex: 100,
                }}
                options={{
                    types: [],
                    componentRestrictions: { country: "us" },
                }}
                onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
                    handleClickGolfCourse(place);
                }}
            />
            <button
                onClick={handleClearSearchInput}
                className="active:opacity-50"
                style={{
                    marginLeft: 8,
                    borderRadius: 8,
                    paddingInline: 8,
                    backgroundColor: grayMid,
                    paddingBlock: 4,
                }}>
                Clear
            </button>
            {/* Map */}
            <Map
                center={center}
                zoom={zoom}
                listOfCoordinates={listOfCoordinates}
                handleOnRightClick={handleOnRightClick}
                handleOnDragEndMarker={handleOnDragEndMarker}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddGolfCoursePage;
```

Component

```
import { GoogleCoords } from "@/typings";
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";

interface Props {
    center: GoogleCoords;
    zoom: number;
    listOfCoordinates: GoogleCoords[];
    handleOnRightClick: any;
    handleOnDragEndMarker: any;
}

const Map = ({
    center,
    zoom,
    listOfCoordinates,
    handleOnRightClick,
    handleOnDragEndMarker,
}: Props) => {
    const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: "google-map-script",
        googleMapsApiKey: "API_KEY",
    });

    return (
        <>
            {isLoaded && (
                <GoogleMap
                    mapContainerStyle={{ width: 600, height: 600 }}
                    options={{
                        streetViewControl: false,
                        mapTypeId: "satellite",
                    }}
                    center={center}
                    zoom={zoom}
                    tilt={0}
                    onRightClick={handleOnRightClick}
                    clickableIcons={false}>
                    {listOfCoordinates.map((point, index) => (
                        <Marker
                            draggable={true}
                            onDragEnd={(e) => handleOnDragEndMarker(e, index)}
                            key={index}
                            position={point}
                        />
                    ))}
                </GoogleMap>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default Map;
```

Here is the error: You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

I need both of these things on the same page. What can I do to accomplish this? Thanks.

Here is a bunch of random stuff that I'm writing so that it will allow my post to be made. It won't allow me to make a post when I have this high of a code to text ratio. Hopefully this text will be able to bring that ratio down a little bit so that I can finally figure out how to do this after hours and hours of trying to figure it out. ChatGPT is an absolute joke. I need a smart human to prove that AI will not replace us all. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is it's the `useJsApiLoader()` call.  Could you hoist that into the page and provide the `isLoaded` state to the `<GoogleMap />` components as props?

Comment: Just tried it. The same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `Autocomplete` component from `react-google-autocomplete` and the `GoogleMap` component from `@react-google-maps/api` are loading the Google Maps JavaScript API independently.

To solve this issue, you can try using the `usePlacesAutocomplete` hook from the `react-places-autocomplete` package

```
npm install react-places-autocomplete
```

Modify `AddGolfCoursePage` component to use the `PlacesAutocomplete` component:

```
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import PlacesAutocomplete, { geocodeByAddress, getLatLng } from "react-places-autocomplete";


const AddGolfCoursePage = () => {
  // Your existing state variables and functions here
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");

  // Handle place selection
  const handleSelect = async (address) => {
    setAddress(address);
    const results = await geocodeByAddress(address);
    const latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
    handleClickGolfCourse(latLng);
  };

  // Modify your return statement
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
      {/* Search Input */}
      <PlacesAutocomplete
        value={address}
        onChange={setAddress}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        searchOptions={{
          types: [],
          componentRestrictions: { country: "us" },
        }}
      >
        {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
          <div>
            <input
              {...getInputProps({
                placeholder: "Search Places ...",
                className: "location-search-input",
                style: {
                  width: "50%",
                  marginBottom: 8,
                  paddingInline: 8,
                  paddingBlock: 4,
                  borderRadius: 8,
                  zIndex: 100,
                },
              })}
            />
            <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
              {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
              {suggestions.map((suggestion) => {
                const style = suggestion.active
                  ? { backgroundColor: "#fafafa", cursor: "pointer" }
                  : { backgroundColor: "#ffffff", cursor: "pointer" };
                return (
                  <div {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, { style })}>
                    {suggestion.description}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </PlacesAutocomplete>
      {/* The rest of your component here */}
    </div>
  );
};
```